# How to script elements embedded within an <iFrame> tag?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

I am using Firefox and i have a page which has an  Tag. 
The contents embedded within this tag cannot be seen from normal "View Page source" option. So i installed Firebug plugin and i can get see the contents using Firebug. My issue is, i cannot script any of these elements using FireWatir. Anybody has any ideas how to do this using Firewatir? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the iframe and parent on the same domain?

Comment: yes they are in the same domain.

Comment: Please, reformat your question so it's not on one gigantic line.

Answer (score 1):

You can only script the iframe's page if it comes from the same domain. If so, you can access the iframe's document by doing `iframe.contentDocument`. You can also access the iframe's window by doing `iframe.contentWindow`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 0):

Watir and FireWatir should not have problems with frames. Take a look at [Frames](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames) page at Watir wiki for more information.

You did not say what is the problem. Some relevant HTML and your Watir code would help.

I would also suggest that you post this at [Watir list](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/) too.